# How to count cells with color that contain string in a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I need to count the cells that have a color and contain a string within a range

When I add a 3rd param it says Range not found line 14 which is  `var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);`

Here is what I have tried so far but only get `#value` and says *range not found*.

```
/**
* @param {range} countRange Range to be evaluated
* @param {range} colorRef Cell with background color to be searched for in countRange
* @param {range} comparisonRef cell with string to be searched for in colorRef
* @return {number}
* @customfunction
*/

function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef,comparisonRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  
  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();

  var count = 0;
  
  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color && values[i][j].slice(0,2) == comparisonRefValue) //Count++ only if there is a color match and a model match
        count=count+1;
  return count;
};
```

Function used as such:

```
=countColoredCells(C5:I16,J7,A3)
```

Updated code:
If I replace comparisonRefValue variable with "string" it works as expected as long as I only pass 2 variables the 3rd breaks the function.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] How are you using the script?

Comment: @Rubén i created a custom script in google sheets using the script editor, and call the function within a cell. it seems my code works but if i add the 3rd param it breaks and says that the Range was not found.

Comment: I took a quick look to the code and found a syntax error: `comparisonRef.getValue`: The parenthesis are missing

Comment: Regarding the error on line 14, it occurs b/c the regular expression in the previous line returns "C5:I16,J7". You have to change the regular expression.

Comment: @Rubén would you mind showing me what to change the reg expression to ?

Comment: Unless there is a better way to achive what i want which is to get the count of a range, that has a color of something and contains a given string